# pivot return actual rating values as presented in source data

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Noob question. So I have a data set provided to me which shows actual percentage ratings but no actual nor target columns that came along with it. Moreover, I have a weighed performance calculation based from other rows using DAX function.

My data set looks something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZWky.png)

Ideally, what I would want is to have those ratings on the last column be included on my weighed performance measure as shown below:

dax weighed perf measure=([RUN %]*.3)+([NU %]*.3) + ([CE_%]*.1) + ([OFFTAKE %]*.3)

However, with those ratings have no actual nor target values, I seem to be encountering a problem which I thing would require the 'distinct' function.

Comment: Please don't write in all upper-case, not even in the title. It's considered shouting, and shouting is rude.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude duly noted and thanks for the tip!